# What is the best way to display a filtered List View in SharePoint?

Tags: list, view, sharepoint-2010, filter, sharepoint-designer

We got a standard-webpart, which displays the document library using views. We can use these views using the SharePoint Designer to customize to our customers needs.

Now the customer wants to have filter/search - option that is used on the title of the documents.

What would be the best ways without writing custom code?

Can it even be done just using SharePoint-Designer and standard-webparts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to this in sharepoint 2007, and i believe this is also applicable in sharepoint 2010, check this site for more info http://sharethelearning.blogspot.com/2007/03/filtering-list-by-partial-match.html

this is by using data view web parts.